# ZF-2 get module name in module Controller file action method

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to get current module name in its controller action method

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
 public function initAction()
{
  parent::initAction();

 die(var_dump(module name here));   
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it from the current `namespace`.

Within your controller action you can do this :

```
public function initAction()
{
  parent::initAction();
  $controllerClass = get_class($this);
  $moduleName = substr($controllerClass, 0, strpos($controllerClass, '\\'));
  die($moduleName);  
}
```

**Example :**

- namespace : `Administration\Controller;`
- Output : `Administration`

Answer (score 4):

I think easiest way to getting current module name is using magic `__NAMESPACE__` constant.

In your controller, try this:

```
$modulename = explode('\\', __NAMESPACE__, -1);
var_dump($modulename); // [0] => 'Application'
```

You can also get a list of loaded modules via ModuleManager like this:

```
$manager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ModuleManager');
$manager->getLoadedModules();
```

Comment: I really love the idea of module manager clean and concise but how i can get the name of current module from 
$manager->getLoadedModules();

Comment: @PradeepSrivastava The answer is you can't. `$manager->getLoadedModules();` returns an array which contains the names of the loaded modules. You can for example check weither a module is loaded or not (`if(in_array('moduleName',$manager->getLoadedModules()))`)